# Any tips for a Sybase developer learning SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I'm an experienced Sybase developer (10+ years) looking to branch out into SQLServer. Does anyone have any advice on good courses / books to help me transition? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer originally came from Sybase so I don't think you're going to have any major issues. Still, you might find this article helpful.

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/Migrating-from-Sybase-to-SQL-Server/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a tool - **SQL Server Migration Assistant for Sybase** that automates porting of your database from Sybase ASE to SQL Server 2005 or 2008 (including T-SQL, e.g. in your stored procedures) and you may find some useful documentation regarding migration process there too:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-sybase.aspx

Maybe you should also look at new features of SQL Server 2005/2008 more closely (in comparison with SQL Server 2000) because at least ASE 12.5 was more close to SQL Server 2000 (for example, you had no varchar(max)/varbinary(max)/nvarchar(max), newer MS' T-SQL enhancements are not likely to be available in Sybase because I doubt Sybase likes to add every feature Microsoft adds :) ).

Answer (score 0):

For a developer I really don't think there is anything you should be worried about. The Sybase origins of SQL Server will clearly show up in all common tasks.

One thing I would recommend is to go over the features that appeared in SQL Server since 2005 and 2008 releases, specially 2005. You want to give them a cursory look just to understand what they do and to be prepared to use them in your arsenal: Crypto functions, CLR procedures, XML data type, varchar/varbinary(MAX) types, Service Broker, snapshot isolation, filestream storage, MERGE statement, common table expressions and recursive queries.

A book that is targeted specifically at developers for SQL 2005 should also be of elp, like [Expert SQL Server 2005 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059729X) perhaps. Make sure is a new content book, not a reprint of a SQL 2000 book updated for 2005. For more advanced coverage, the [Inside SQL 2005](http://www.insidesqlserver.com/thebooks.html) series is very good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest hands on work would be good and just see how you get on.

Have you a favourite Sybase DB to port, for example, reading up as you go along?